# Sending LinkedHashMap to intent

Tags: android, android-intent, linkedhashmap

I want send LinkedHashMap to another Intent. But I don't known what method for extras is allowable.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  LinkedHashMap<Integer, String[]> listItems = extras.get(LIST_TXT);
```

Answer (score 6):

You cannot reliably send a `LinkedHashMap` as an `Intent` extra. When you call `putExtra()` with a `LinkedHashMap`, Android sees that the object implements the `Map` interface, so it serializes the name/value pairs into the extras `Bundle` in the `Intent`. When you want to extract it on the other side, what you get is a `HashMap`, not a `LinkedHashMap`. Unfortunately, this `HashMap` that you get has lost the ordering that was the reason you wanted to use a `LinkedHashMap` in the first place.

The only reliable way to do this is to convert the `LinkedHashMap` to an ordered array, put the array into the `Intent`, extract the array from the `Intent` on the receiving end, and then recreate the `LinkedHashMap`.

See [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300886/linkedlist-put-into-intent-extra-gets-recast-to-arraylist-when-retrieving-in-nex/12305459#12305459) for more gory details.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to convert it to ArrayList of the same type  
 examble :

```
 LinkedHashSet<Long> uniqueIds = new LinkedHashSet();
 ArrayList<Long> ids = new ArrayList(uniqueIds);
    
 Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), UserStoryActivity.class);
 intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(FLAG_USERS_STORY_LIST_IDS, (ArrayList) ids);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @David Wasser for pointing out this issue.

I have another approach is to use `Gson` to parse your whatever `map` to `json string`, then put into the `intent`. Less drama!

**Code send:**

```
gson.toJson(data)
```

**Code get back:**

*Kotlin:*

```
gson.fromJson<LinkedHashMap<Int, Int>>(
                    it.getStringExtra(ARG_DATA),
                    object : TypeToken<LinkedHashMap<Int, Int>>() {}.type
                )
```

*Java:*

```
gson.fromJson(
     it.getStringExtra(ARG_DATA),
     new TypeToken<ArrayList<Mountain>>(){}.getType()
);
```