# Passing an LinkedHashMap<Object,String> from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am facing an issue while passing a LinkedHashMap from one Activity to another. I referred all the related post by none of them could solve my problem. Please help me out.

Activity 1:

```
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(this,GMap.class);
LinkedHashMap<TravelMode, String> polyPoints=(LinkedHashMap<TravelMode, String>) gData.values().toArray()[0];
mapIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, polyPoints);
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Activity 2:

```
LinkedHashMap<Object,String>polypoint = (LinkedHashMap<Object, String>)poly.getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

This is the error I m getting while doing this operation.

Error:

```
 ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.util.HashMap (id=830032266720) to java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

Class TravelMode:

```
  class TravelMode implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public String travelMode;

    /**
     * @return the travelMode
     */
    public String getTravelMode() {
        return travelMode;
    }

    /**
     * @param travelMode the travelMode to set
     */
    public void setTravelMode(String travelMode) {
        this.travelMode = travelMode;
    }

    public TravelMode(String travelMode) {
        super();
        this.travelMode = travelMode;
    }
}
```

I tried all the possibilities of retrieving like this one below, But still I getting the same error :(

```
HashMap<?,?>hashPoly= (HashMap<?, ?>)poly.getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
LinkedHashMap<TravelMode, String> polypoint= ((LinkedHashMap<TravelMode, String>)hashPoly);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly cast from a `HashMap` to a `LinkedHashMap`. You should be able to do this instead:

```
LinkedHashMap<Object,String>polypoint = new LinkedHashMap<Object, String>();
```

and then add the previous `HashMap` with `putAll`:

```
polypoint.putAll(polyPoints);
```

Comment: Thanks. It solves the problem. But now the order is getting changed. But I want to retain the order in which the list is sent and that's the reason Y I was using linkedHashMap. But now in the second activity the order is changed.

Comment: The order is changed because Android converts the `LinkedHashMap` to a `HashMap` when you call `putExtra()`, thereby discarding all the ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Android converts the `LinkedHashMap` to a `HashMap` when you call `putExtra()`. This discards the ordering, which is why you want to use a `LinkedHashMap` in the first place.

To get around this, you should convert the `LinkedHashMap` to an ordered array, and put the array in the `Intent` extras. On the receiving end you can then recreate the `LinkedHashMap` from the ordered array (if necessary), or just use the array as is.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38960732/769265 and [LinkedList put into Intent extra gets recast to ArrayList when retrieving in next activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300886/linkedlist-put-into-intent-extra-gets-recast-to-arraylist-when-retrieving-in-nex/12305459#12305459) for more details.