# Android - LinkedHashMap cannot be passed between Activities

Tags: android, android-intent, serialization, linkedhashmap

I have a very strange problem. All I want to do is pass a `LinkedHashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>` (I am just experimenting here and the I would like the choice of data structure to remain unchanged regardless of performance overhead) object from one Activity to another via an `Intent`. I tried two approaches after initializing and populating my data structure:

```
 LinkedHashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>> mData = new LinkedHashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>();
//insert data into LinkedHashMap
```

Approach 1:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);             
 // as a Serializable
 intent.putExtra("DATA",mData)
 startActivity(intent);
```

Approach 2:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);             
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putSerializable("LIST",mData);
 intent.putExtra("DATA",bundle)
 startActivity(intent);
```

And in the receiving Activity:

For Approach 1:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
mData = (LinkedHashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>) intent.getSerializableExtra("DATA");
```

For Approach 2:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("DATA");
mData = (LinkedHashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>) bundle.getSerializable("LIST");
```

And I keep running into this issue:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedHashMap
            at com.matchify.TestActivity.onCreate(TestActivity.java:56)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What am I doing wrong ? Apologies if I have missed something very obvious.

Comment: You aren't doing anything wrong. Android converts the `LinkedHashMap` to a `HashMap` when you call `purExtra()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164050/sending-linkedhashmap-to-intent/38960732#38960732 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300886/linkedlist-put-into-intent-extra-gets-recast-to-arraylist-when-retrieving-in-nex/12305459#12305459 for more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked `LinkedHashMap`'s source code and found the data structure that stores iteration order is declared as `transient`:

```
transient LinkedEntry<K, V> header;
```

So even if `LinkedHashMap` is returned to the new Activity, the map would be broken as far as iteration is concerned, which may be the reason why `HashMap` is returned instead.

If you don't need guaranteed iteration order, just cast it as `HashMap` in the 2nd `Activity`, otherwise you may have to write your own `Parcelable` to preserve the ordering.

Comment: Android converts the `LinkedHashMap` into a `HashMap` when adding it to the `Bundle`. It's an Android idiosyncrasy. The easiest way to get around this is to convert the `LinkedHashMap` into an ordered array of whatevers, which you add to the `Bundle`, then extract the array on the receiving end and reconstruct the `LinkedHashMap`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38960732/769265 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300886/linkedlist-put-into-intent-extra-gets-recast-to-arraylist-when-retrieving-in-nex/12305459#12305459 for more details

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("factorsDataMap", mData);
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MoodSummary.class); 
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Try this, Hope it works. Tell me if you still have problem.

Comment: This is exactly my second approach. Strangely the JavaDoc says that LinkedHashMap is serializable but I suspect it really is.

Comment: only pass bundle in intent.putExtras(bundle);  not this intent.putExtra("DATA",bundle)

Comment: Is this any different from using a key value-pair for a Bundle in an Intent ? The result is the same though.

Answer (score -2):

Try this hope you help!

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("hashmap", hashMap);
startActivity(intent);
```

//receiving Activity:

```
hashMap = (HashMap<String,String>)intent.getExtras().getSerializable("hashmap");
LinkedHashMap<String,String> linkedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(hashMap);
```