# LinkedList put into Intent extra gets recast to ArrayList when retrieving in next activity

Tags: android, android-intent

A behaviour i'm observing w.r.t passing serializable data as intent extra is quite strange, and I just wanted to clarify whether there's something I'm not missing out on.

So the thing I was trying to do is that in `ActivtyA` I put a `LinkedList` instance into the `intent` I created for starting the next activity - `ActivityB`.

```
LinkedList<Item> items = (some operation);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra(AppConstants.KEY_ITEMS, items);
```

In the `onCreate` of `ActivityB`, I tried to retrieve the `LinkedList` extra as follows -

```
LinkedList<Item> items = (LinkedList<Item>) getIntent()
                             .getSerializableExtra(AppConstants.KEY_ITEMS);
```

On running this, I repeatedly got a `ClassCastException` in `ActivityB`, at the line above. Basically, the exception said that I was receiving an `ArrayList`. Once I changed the code above to receive an `ArrayList` instead, everything worked just fine.

Now I can't just figure out from the existing documentation whether this is the expected behaviour on Android when passing serializable List implementations. Or perhaps, there's something fundamentally wrong w/ what I'm doing.

Thanks.

Comment: but is there any particular reason why for `LinkedList` this behaviour occurs, whereas, if i were to have added an `ArrayList` instance as extra data on the `intent` everything would be fine. And, i won't need to use `Parcelable`?

Comment: +1 for the interesting question. I spent some time thinking about this and was so intrigued I went to figure it out for myself. Now you and I are both smarter (see my answer).

Comment: @anirvan You can't pass an `ArrayList<CustomObject>` using the you way you have done. Only raw type of ArrayList is allowed that is `String` or `Integer`

Comment: @LalitPoptani you're mistaken. As long as the `CustomObject` implements `Serializable` there's nothing wrong in doing so. And it works just fine.

Comment: @anirvan yes you are right, but you have to implement `Serializable` without which I won't be possible.

Comment: I f you are just wanting to use Serializable then you create a class with getter setter of LinkedList and implement Serializable and pass it.

Comment: @LalitPoptani that would certainly be quite an overkill. Besides, that's not the point of my asking the question. It's more about understanding the behaviour. There can be *many* hacks. David's answer pretty much nails it.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I can tell you why this is happening, but you aren't going to like it ;-)

First a bit of background information:

**Extras** in an `Intent` are basically an Android `Bundle` which is basically a `HashMap` of key/value pairs. So when you do something like

```
intent.putExtra(AppConstants.KEY_ITEMS, items);
```

Android creates a new `Bundle` for the extras and adds a map entry to the `Bundle` where the key is `AppConstants.KEY_ITEMS` and the value is **items** (which is your LinkedList object).

This is all fine and good, and if you were to look at the extras bundle after your code executes you will find that it contains a `LinkedList`. Now comes the interesting part...

When you call `startActivity()` with the extras-containing Intent, Android needs to convert the extras from a map of key/value pairs into a byte stream. Basically it needs to **serialize the Bundle**. It needs to do that because it may start the activity in another process and in order to do that it needs to serialize/deserialize the objects in the Bundle so that it can recreate them in the new process. It also needs to do this because Android saves the contents of the Intent in some system tables so that it can regenerate the Intent if it needs to later.

In order to serialize the `Bundle` into a byte stream, it goes through the map in the bundle and gets each key/value pair. Then it takes each "value" (which is some kind of object) and tries to determine what kind of object it is so that it can serialize it in the most efficient way. To do this, it checks the object type against a list of **known object types**. The list of "known object types" contains things like `Integer`, `Long`, `String`, `Map`, `Bundle` and unfortunately also `List`. So if the object is a `List` (of which there are many different kinds, including `LinkedList`) it serializes it and marks it as an object of type `List`.

When the `Bundle` is deserialized, ie: when you do this:

```
LinkedList<Item> items = (LinkedList<Item>)
        getIntent().getSerializableExtra(AppConstants.KEY_ITEMS);
```

it produces an `ArrayList` for all objects in the `Bundle` of type `List`.

There isn't really anything you can do to change this behaviour of Android. At least now you know why it does this.

Just so that you know: I actually wrote a small test program to verify this behaviour and I have looked at the source code for `Parcel.writeValue(Object v)` which is the method that gets called from `Bundle` when it converts the map into a byte stream.

**Important Note:** Since `List` is an interface this means that any class that implements `List` that you put into a `Bundle` will come out as an `ArrayList`. 
It is also interesting that `Map` is also in the list of "known object types" which means that no matter what kind of `Map` object you put into a `Bundle` (for example `TreeMap`, `SortedMap`, or any class that implements the `Map` interface), you will always get a `HashMap` out of it.

Comment: My, oh my - might I first say that *yes, I really don't like this*. After all, the whole concept of "*known object types*" sounds like some one wanted to cut corners when building that part of the logic. And also, if this be the case, they should've actually made it a point to prevent all "*not-so-known*" object types from implementing `Serializable`, or, not supporting `Serializable` at all within intent `extras`. Anyways, I can't thank you enough, and yes, we're much the smarter for what you've found.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Saved me hours of debugging.

Comment: Thanks David, this saved me... I had the same issue with savedInstanceState that was passed to my fragment - and I could not figure out why Android insisted on giving me an ArrayList...

Answer (score 5):

The answer by [@David Wasser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12305459/535871) is right on in terms of diagnosing the problem. This post is to share how I handled it.

The problem with any `List` object coming out as an `ArrayList` isn't horrible, because you can always do something like

```
LinkedList<String> items = new LinkedList<>(
    (List<String>) intent.getSerializableExtra(KEY));
```

which will add all the elements of the deserialized list to a new `LinkedList`.

The problem is much worse when it comes to `Map`, because you may have tried to serialize a `LinkedHashMap` and have now lost the element ordering.

Fortunately, there's a (relatively) painless way around this: define your own serializable wrapper class. You can do it for specific types or do it generically:

```
public class Wrapper <T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {
    private T wrapped;

    public Wrapper(T wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    public T get() {
        return wrapped;
    }
}
```

Then you can use this to hide your `List`, `Map`, or other data type from Android's type checking:

```
intent.putExtra(KEY, new Wrapper<>(items));
```

and later:

```
items = ((Wrapper<LinkedList<String>>) intent.getSerializableExtra(KEY)).get();
```

Comment: You probably meant `public class Wrapper <T extends Serializable> implements Serializable`

Comment: @SergioSerra - Indeed. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IcePick library and are having this problem you can use Ted Hoop's  technique with a custom bundler to avoid having to deal with Wrapper instances in your code.

```
public class LinkedHashmapBundler implements Bundler<LinkedHashMap> {

 @Override
 public void put(String s, LinkedHashMap val, Bundle bundle) {
    bundle.putSerializable(s, new Wrapper<>(val));
 }

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 @Override
 public LinkedHashMap get(String s, Bundle bundle) {
   return ((Wrapper<LinkedHashMap>) bundle.getSerializable(s)).get();
 }
} 

// Use it like this
@State(LinkedHashmapBundler.class) LinkedHasMap map
```