# Pass a TreeMap from one activity to other

Tags: android, android-intent, treemap

I have a

```
TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Video>> mShows = new TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Video>>();
```

and I'm trying to pass from one activity to another. I have tried

"[putExtra treeMap returns HashMap cannot be cast to TreeMap android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960153/putextra-treemap-returns-hashmap-cannot-be-cast-to-treemap-android)"

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     Intent i = getIntent();
     Bundle bun = i.getBundleExtra("lascategorias");
     mCategories = bun.getStringArray("categories");
    mShows = new TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Video>>(Map<String,ArrayList<Video>> getIntent().getExtras().get("map"));         
}
```

but it says that Map, String and the ArrayList cannot be resolved to a variable where I have (Map>)

This is how I add it

```
protected void onPostExecute(final String json) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "decoding...");
        if (json == null)
            return;
        try {
            final URI base = new URI(mUrl);
            final JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(json);
            final JSONArray ja = jso.getJSONArray("categories");
            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                final JSONObject list = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                final ArrayList<Video> vidList = new ArrayList<Video>(10);
                mShows.put(list.getString("name"), vidList);
                final JSONArray videos = list.getJSONArray("videos");
                for (int j = 0; j < videos.length(); j++) {
                    final JSONObject vids = videos.getJSONObject(j);
                    final JSONArray sources = vids.getJSONArray("sources");
                    try {
                        final Video v = new Video(base.resolve(vids.getString("thumb")),
                                base.resolve(sources.getString(0)), vids.getString("title"),
                                vids.getString("subtitle"), vids.getString("description"));
                        vidList.add(v);

                        // The rare case that I've got more than one
                        for (int k = 1; k < sources.length(); k++) {
                            v.mSource.add(base.resolve(sources.getString(k)));
                        }
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException expected) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Bad Json.");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (final JSONException je) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "An error in the JSON." + je.getMessage());
        } catch (final URISyntaxException se) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "URI syntax error" + se.getMessage());
        }
        //onDataComplete();
        mCategories = getCategories();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putStringArray("categories", mCategories);
        //b.p
        Intent i = new Intent("com.video.tv.MainActivity" );
        i.putExtra("las Categorias", b);
        i.putExtra("map", mShows);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}

I declared mShows earlier
public TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Video>> mShows = new TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Video>>();
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: I get an error saying that Map<String, ArrayList<Video>> cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Please post more code (where do you call the above). Also, your construction map = new TreeMap<...>(...) getIntent... is not correct.

Comment: i've added the changes @Melquiades. let me know if you need something else

Comment: Disregard my previous answer, I was wrong :) See the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one closing bracket missing, just before getIntent(). Correct form:

```
mShows = new TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Video>>((TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Video>>) getIntent().getExtras().get("map"));
```

Comment: i thought the error was solved but i get java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.treemap

Comment: i've added the whole function @Melquiades