# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.TreeMap

Tags: android, android-intent, hashmap, classcastexception, treemap

I stuff a TreeMap into an intent:

```
private TreeMap<Long, Long> mSelectedItems;

...

mSelectedItems = new TreeMap<Long, Long>();

...

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("results", mSelectedItems);

setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

and then attempt to read it back out in the calling activity:

```
TreeMap<Long, Long> results = (TreeMap<Long, Long>)
    data.getSerializableExtra("results");
```

which causes:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(26868): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.TreeMap
```

Well, sure, but since I'm not using HashMap anywhere in the code, and since TreeMap implements Serializable, this should work without error, no? Why is android trying to force a class on me that I'm not using?

Comment: Have you even tried searching for a solution? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960153/putextra-treemap-returns-hashmap-cannot-be-cast-to-treemap-android), [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300886/linkedlist-put-into-intent-extra-gets-recast-to-arraylist-when-retrieving-in-nex/12305459#12305459)

Comment: Actually I did, but apparently I didn't use the correct search terms. The first link doesn't mention ClassCastException, and the second doesn't mention either kind of Map.

Answer (score 6):

The first [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960153/putextra-treemap-returns-hashmap-cannot-be-cast-to-treemap-android) that Emmanuel provided is the *exact* same issue you are having. It doesn't specifically mention that exact error but it is implied.

The issue is that when your `TreeMap` is serialized it will come back as a `HashMap`. Completely explained by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12305459/3286163) which Emmanuel also provided.

So simply doing the follow shall resolve your issue:

```
TreeMap<Long, Long> results = new TreeMap<Long, Long>((HashMap<Long, Long>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("results"));
```

Basically populates your `results` TreeMap with the `HashMap` returned from the bundle.

Also upvote those answers in the links provided if this resolves your issue.

Comment: Regardless, neither link was returned in either a google search or as a suggested possible question when I added this one. 

I've upvoted the answers provided since they did resolve the issue.

Comment: @tbm Oh I see. That happens sometimes, you search for something but can't find it although there is something. Anyway, since it resolved your issue please accept answer (instead of mentioning as a comment). Glad it worked out for you in the end.