# how to pass the linkedList<customizedType> from Activity A to Activity B In android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am doing fine with pass normal data between two activities. But I were stuck  when I try to pass a linkedList between two activities. I have no idea if I intent.putExtra("key",linkedList). how to receive the result using get***, seems no getLinkedList option.

Please give me a simple example, I am a new to android.

Comment: This should help ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300886/linkedlist-put-into-intent-extra-gets-recast-to-arraylist-when-retrieving-in-nex

Comment: I don't understand, hope someone can give a simple example to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `intent.putExtra("yourkey", linkedList);`

In your B activity, just use `getIntent().getExtras().get("key");` 
`getExtras().get()` suppose you will get an Object (like a LinkedList)

Hope helps

Comment: This won't work. The object retrieved will be an ArrayList instead of a linkedlist. Parcelable must be used.You should see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300886/linkedlist-put-into-intent-extra-gets-recast-to-arraylist-when-retrieving-in-nex