# TreeMap in Intent becomes HashMap

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to pass a `TreeMap` through an Intent from one activity to another one. But somehow Android converts it into a `HashMap` on its way.

In a newly created project with two blank activities, running `MainActivity` in the emulator produces a `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.TreeMap`.

First activity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.TreeMap;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("map", new TreeMap<Long, Long>());
        //TreeMap<Long, Long> m = (TreeMap<Long, Long>) i.getSerializableExtra("map");
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Second activity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.TreeMap;


public class SecondActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        TreeMap<Long, Long> m = (TreeMap<Long, Long>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("map");
    }

}
```

Strangely enough, the commented code in the first activity runs without any problem.

Comment: This seems to answer your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300886/linkedlist-put-into-intent-extra-gets-recast-to-arraylist-when-retrieving-in-nex/12305459#12305459

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by pbabcdefp in his comment above, the cause of the problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300886/linkedlist-put-into-intent-extra-gets-recast-to-arraylist-when-retrieving-in-nex/12305459#12305459). A more detailed explanation can be found in [this blog post](https://medium.com/the-wtf-files/the-mysterious-case-of-the-bundle-and-the-map-7b15279a794e).

An easy to implement solution to it is [using Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19700319/4687139).