# Why is the system automatically converting my LinkedHashMap to HashMap while passing it in an Intent as a Serializable?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, classcastexception, linkedhashmap

I am getting

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

at `LinkedHashMap<String, String> dataHashMap = (LinkedHashMap<String, String>) intent.getSerializableExtra("tests.test.MyApp.A.EXTRA_KEY");` in the given (relevant parts of) code of Activity B.

---

1. In Fragment A, I have the following check:

   ```
   Log.i(TAG, "THE TYPE OF THE MAP RETURNED FROM populateSelectedEntryList(selectedResultEntry) IS " + 
   populateSelectedEntryList(selectedResultEntry).getClass().getSimpleName()
   + ".");//******PRINTS LinkedHashMap**********************
   ```

which **prints `LinkedHashMap`**.

2. In Activity B, I have the following check:

   ```
   LinkedHashMap<String, String> dataHashMap = (LinkedHashMap<String, String>)intent.getSerializableExtra("tests.test.MyApp.A.EXTRA_KEY");//**********ClassCastException*****************
   ```

   which **prints `HashMap`**.

   ---

The question is **why? Why is the system converting my LinkedHashMap to HashMap. How do i force the LinkedHashMap to continue to be a LinkedHashMap when it is passed in an intent as a Serializable?**

***RELEVANT PARTS OF CODE:***

In Fragment A,

```
public class A extends Fragment {
  ...

  public void onListItemClick(...) { 
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), B.class);
    ...
    intent.putExtra("tests.test.MyApp.A.EXTRA_KEY", populateSelectedEntryList(selectedResultEntry));
    Log.i(TAG, "THE TYPE OF THE MAP RETURNED FROM populateSelectedEntryList(selectedResultEntry) IS "
 + populateSelectedEntryList(selectedResultEntry).getClass().getSimpleName() + ".");//******PRINTS LinkedHashMap**********************
    startActivity(intent);
  };

  ...

  private LinkedHashMap<String, String> populateSelectedEntryList(MyParser.Entry selectedResultEntry) {
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> selectedEntryMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    ...
    return selectedEntryMap;
  }
}
```

And inside Activity B,

```
public class B extends FragmentActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> dataHashMap = (LinkedHashMap<String, String>) intent.getSerializableExtra("tests.test.MyApp.A.EXTRA_KEY");
  } //**********ClassCastException*****************
  ...
}
```

Comment: You should reduce the question to the smallest amount of compilable code needed to reproduce the issue. There are lots of ... in your code which makes it hard to see what is going on. You haven't even posted the method that returns the HashMap (Intent.getSerializableExtra)

Comment: It's the same with `LinkedList` being converted to `ArrayList`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300886/linkedlist-put-into-intent-extra-gets-recast-to-arraylist-when-retrieving-in-nex

Comment: @pbabcdefp Oh, that is the most terrible thing that has happened today. So there is no solution to this? I need this to work =(

Comment: @Solace You can store it as a pair of `Lists`, one for the keys and one for the values. If you try to store it as a `Map`, there is no way to stop it being turned into a `HashMap` at the other end, and the order of the keys will be lost.

Comment: Is the ordering implied by the LinkedHashMap important to your app?

Comment: @pbabcdefp That sounds like a lot of memory overhead, isn't it? Actually I need an _ordered, key-value pair data-structure_ which provides facility of  `index-based search`? Can you suggest something? If there is no option, I'll have to use a pair of Lists, in a Bundle probably.

Comment: Well if it's a different order you want, you should be using a `TreeMap` anyway. You'll still have the same problem. I'm only talking about converting it into a pair of `List`s in order to put it in the `Intent` and recover it at the other end; you should not be *using* a pair of `List`s. In terms of memory overhead, a pair of `List`s is **less** memory intensive than a `TreeMap` or a `LinkedHashMap` because it doesn't require a load of `Map.Entry` objects.

Comment: @schtever Oh NO no no, the order of insertion IS important. Sorry I was mistaken. I am going to remove the above comment where I said it isn't important.

Comment: @pbabcdefp That's a very useful comment. Although it provides a solution which seems 'hacky' but is a solution to this problem nonetheless, and seems to be the only solution. If you can post it as an answer, it will be useful for future visitors.

Comment: @Solace I'll do that. Unfortunately, this is android, so you have to use horrible hacks like this all the time...

Comment: @pbabcdefp Thank you. Are there that kind of hacks in real applications, which a lot of people use?

Comment: I'm not really an expert on android. All I know is that I have to use hacks like this all the time, but I don't find myself doing horrible things like that when programming in pure Java or C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The explanation for this is given here: [LinkedList put into Intent extra gets recast to ArrayList when retrieving in next activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300886/linkedlist-put-into-intent-extra-gets-recast-to-arraylist-when-retrieving-in-nex)

If you want to recover a `LinkedList`, or a `Map` where the order of the keys is not important, you can use the solution of @schtever. If you want to recover a `LinkedHashMap` or a `TreeMap` and the order of the keys **is** important, it is a bit more tricky.

One possible solution is to convert the `Map` into a pair of `List`s, as demonstrated below:

Activity1:

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Map<Integer, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
        map.put(1, "ONE");
        map.put(2, "TWO");
        map.put(3, "THREE");

        ArrayList<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            keys.add(entry.getKey());
            values.add(entry.getValue());
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        intent.putExtra("KEYS", keys);
        intent.putExtra("VALUES", values);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Activity2:

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        List<Integer> keys = (List<Integer>) intent.getSerializableExtra("KEYS");
        List<String> values = (List<String>) intent.getSerializableExtra("VALUES");

        Map<Integer, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
        for (int i = 0, n = keys.size(); i < n; i++)
            map.put(keys.get(i), values.get(i));

        Log.i("Activity2",  "" + map);
    }
}
```

This is a bit of a hack, and it's extremely verbose, but it works. I would be interested to know if there is a better solution to this.

Comment: This also helped me with similiar problem in onRestoreInstanceState / onSaveInstanceState thx

Comment: In my case, fragment arguments were deserialized when the activity was recreated and the LinkedHashMap came out of the Bundle as HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

If ordering isn't important, recreate the LinkedHashMap using the returned HashMap:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> dataHashMap = new LinkedHashMap(intent.getSerializableExtra("tests.test.MyApp.A.EXTRA_KEY"));
```

Comment: That won't work. Presumably the OP is using a `LinkedHashMap` in order to keep the keys in insertion order.

Comment: But that won't restore the order.

Comment: @pbabcdefp Revised the answer with that caveat and asked OP to clarify if that's a requirement.

Comment: Fair enough. It is a useful answer anyway, as it completely solves the problem for the `LinkedList` problem.

Comment: The order of insertion IS important to my app unfortunately. =(

Comment: I agree, it's a useful answer, I upvoted it. Thank you for answering.