# How to pass Properties object from an intent to another?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, properties, classcastexception

I have this piece of code in **Activity A**:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();

/** Fill up properties here */

Intent intent = new Intent(this,Another.class);
intent.putExtra("prop",properties);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now..I try grant that extra from the **Activity B** (through Intent's Bundle) by:

```
Properties properties = (Properties) bundle.getSerializable("prop");
```

But I getting java.lang.**ClassCastException** followed by that message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{gr.kanellis.sqlify/gr.kanellis.sqlify.activities.DatabaseView}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.Properties
```

And pointing the line that I cast the Properties object in Activity B.

I can't figure out how to solve this problem.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is `Properties` even `Serializable` ? It would also help to know what information you want to pass. There are several ways, if you want the best answer, be specific.

Comment: Generally, I want to pass something like a HashMap<String,String> and Properties object can simply help me out with this. And yes. It is Serializable.

Comment: Is it too much of a hack for you to use a 3rd party library such as EventBus? With it, you can send **any** object from any place in code to another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("Hello", "Hi!");
/*...*/
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putExtra("prop", properties);
```

Then in your activity you can get it back, but you must cast it as a `HashMap`:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
HashMap<String,String> map= (HashMap<String, String>)bundle.getSerializable("prop");
map.get("Hello")
```

The reason why this works it's completely explained in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300886/linkedlist-put-into-intent-extra-gets-recast-to-arraylist-when-retrieving-in-nex/12305459#12305459) and as a summary it's because `Properties` implements `Map`, and any class that implements Map that you put into a Bundle will come out as a `HashMap`.

If you still need an object of type `Property` you can do this:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.putAll(map);
```

Comment: Well..there is no method name "putSerializable" but just the simple one "putExtra"..

Comment: Are sure? I'm currently testing it, and it has this method. Please note that I'm using the class [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putSerializable%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29), so you should first do "Bundle bundle = new Bundle;" and in that object call the method putSerializable.

Comment: No this is still not working, I getting ClassCastException again :(

Comment: Please read my new answer, as explained in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12305459/1430615) Android works in a way that any class that implements Map that you put into a Bundle will come out as a HashMap. So you must cast it to HashMap, and if you need it, then change it to Properties.

Comment: Yes that's what I done couple minutes ago and solve my problem!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Properties does not implement Serializable **directly** - instead inheriting from HashMap (which is serializable).

A simple solution is to simply call the Properties constructor, passing the HashMap to it:

```
class Properties extends HashMap<String,String> {
     public Properties(HashMap map) {
         super(map);
     }
}
```

Now, when you deserialize, just call:

```
Properties properties = new Properties((HashMap)bundle.getSerializable("prop"));
```

DroidFiddle example here: https://droidfiddle.net/rvcgfcy/2