# Google endpoints Models, how to send data to Intent using Parcelable, Serializable or a JSON String

Tags: java, android, json, google-app-engine, serialization

Hello I have a model class `MeetAppFacebookEvent` generate using GAE endpoints.

I want to pass this Model to another activity using `intent.putExtra` so I make `MeetAppFacebookEvent` Serializable.

However when I try to `getSerializableExtra()` I got the following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to
>   com.appspot.sonorous_zone_440.meet_app.model.MeetAppFacebookEvent

Searching around I found the cause of the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922572/classcastexception-when-retrieving-data-from-bundle-on-android). Now I'm trying to pass the data as a JSON String, using:

`new Gson().toJson(event)`

and

`new Gson().fromJson(json, MeetAppFacebookEvent.class)`

When decoding the JSON String I got this error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid value for field`:

The JSON look fine for me:

```
{
   "description":"ALTERAÇÕES NO EVENTO:\n\nComo a maioria tem compromissos na quinta de manhã, vamos alterar o evento para sexta-feira, dia 21, no Amsterdam Pubbh\n\nVai ter Seu Madruga AC/DC Cover e Banda Charlie\n\nFavor enviar nome na lista no evento da Amsterdam:\n21/02.SEXTA ✭ Amsterdam Pub ✭ SEU MADRUGA (AC/DC Cover) \u0026 CHARLIE (RHCP Cover)\n\n\nValores:\nFEMININO\nENTRADA: R$20,00\nDESCONTO com nome na LISTA: R$10,00 (válido até 00 horas)\n\nMASCULINO\nENTRADA: R$30,00\nDESCONTO com nome na LISTA: R$20,00 (válido até 00 horas)\n\nPromoção da casa: Double Jägermeister!\n\nÉ isso aê! Espero todo mundo lá \u003dD\nLet\u0027s Rock!!!",
   "id":1383874008547940,
   "imageUrl":"https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/t1/1899960_653273534739151_1285485477_n.jpg",
   "isAttending":false,
   "name":"Let\u0027s Rock! Aniversário do Alyson 2.3.12",
   "offset_y":50
}
```

Can someone point me a good way to overcome this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON document is invalid.  Try logging it before decoding.

**Edit**: The JSON document looks fine.  The "id" value would overflow a 32 bit integer though, please check that it goes to a long integer.

Comment: Already done that, it seems fine for me. I Will update my answer with the JSON