# How to convert/cast HashMap to LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, android, casting, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I'm using [Hawk](https://github.com/orhanobut/hawk) as a replacement for `SharedPreferences` in my application.

I'm trying to store a `LinkedHashMap` in it, but for some reason when I pull it back from **Hawk** it returns as a regular `HashMap` and not a `LinkedHashMap`. At this point I crash with a `ClassCastException` as `HashMap` can't be casted to `LinkedHashMap` straight forward.

So the question is how can I convert the returned `HashMap` to be a `LinkedHashMap`?

Comment: Thanks for the challenge. I love a non-trivial question that requires a bit of digging.

Comment: @DavidWasser, Thank you for you detailed answer, for some reason not all people thought it was a decent question.

Comment: I have no idea where the downvotes came from. That surprised me actually.

Comment: @DavidWasser, well some people I guess don't understand the true purpose of this community. Nevermind... Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All the answers suggesting that you can create a `LinkedHashMap` from a `HashMap` are technically correct, but will not give you the desired results :-(

Of course, you can create a `LinkedHashMap` from a `HashMap`, but it isn't guaranteed that the `LinkedHashMap` will have the same order that your original did.

The problem is that your `LinkedHashMap` is serialized when it is stored into the persistent storage as a plain unordered `Map`, which does NOT persist in the ordering of the individual items. When you then extract the object from the persistent storage, it is returned as a plain `HashMap`, and it has lost the "ordering" (which is what you wanted a `LinkedHashMap` for in the first place). If you then create a `LinkedHashMap` from the returned `HashMap`, the ordering will most probably be different from the original.

In order to do this correctly, you should probably convert your `LinkedHashMap` into an ordered array of objects and store this ordered array in the persistent storage. You can then read the ordered array of objects back from the persistent storage and recreate the `LinkedHashMap` with the correct order. Basically, you need to serialize and deserialize the `LinkedHashMap` yourself.

See [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12305459/769265) for more details.

Comment: and to accomplish that, I suggest this code sample: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43142613/1855855

Answer (score 11):

Just create a new LinkedHashMap, since it can take any Map as a constructor argument.

```
LinkedHashMap<Object> newMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(theHashMapReturnedFromHawk);
```

`Object` would be the type you need.

Answer (score 2):

One of [LinkedHashMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)'s constructors accepts a `Map`. It will return a `LinkedHashMap` with the same content as `HashMap`.

Code sample:

```
LinkedHashMap<T> newMap = new LinkedHashMap<T>(hashmap);
```

where `T` is the type of the objects stored in the `HashMap`

Comment: @DavidWasser I did what was asked. You did what was needed. 